# Flask reads .txt and .pdf files from the static folder, but does not read .css and .png

Tags: flask

I'm making a subsite project on Flask, which will be part of the main site (wordpress).

I launch it using gunicorn with the SCRIPT_NAME parameter to indicate that this is a subsite:
`SCRIPT_NAME=/script gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 main:app`

Pages work, url_for works, but css and images are not included! The browser does not find these files (404). Neither through url_for, nor through opening in the browser. Examples:

```
https://my.site.com/script/static/css/styles.css
https://my.site.com/script/static/images/image.png
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for("static", filename="css/styles.css") }}">
```

At the same time, the browser finds txt and pdf! Example:

```
https://my.site.com/script/static/css/styles.txt
https://my.site.com/script/static/file.pdf
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for("static", filename="css/styles.txt") }}"> (True, it will give a MINE-type error, but that’s normal)
```

I even made a function that does send_file when accessing /styles.css and returns /styles.txt. It works, but it's not pretty!

I think this is due to the fact that during development I launched the site as a root site, and while adding it as a subsite, the connection of .css and .png broke. BUT why then does .txt work?

In the Flask code everything is the same as for the site if it were root. Example function:

```
@app.route('/users')
@login_required
def users():
    # If not admin
    if current_user.role != 'admin':
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    users_data = User.query.all()
    users_data.reverse()
    return render_template('users.html', title='Users', users=users_data)
```

Part of Nginx config:

```
location /script {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

The Flask project structure is as follows:

```
-main.py
-config.py
--app
---__init__.py
---routes.py

---templates
----base.html

---static
----file.pdf

----css
-----styles.css
-----styles.txt

----images
-----image.png
```

I tried to specify static_folder='static', and static_folder='../static', and I tried to specify static_folder='app/static', but it did not help. And this is pointless, because txt and pdf files open fine from static folders.

Clearing the cache and running in incognito mode doesn't help either.